# How to set icon url in holder in adapter requesting from google api

Tags: android, kotlin

This is the API I use

[https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?location=-33.8670522,151.1957362&rankby=distance&type=food&key="Your_Key"](https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?location=-33.8670522,151.1957362&rankby=distance&type=food&key=%22Your_Key%22)

as the data looks like the below image as I want to set the icon in a holder:

[image: data looks like]

and this is the xml file which have the `Circular Image`:

```
<com.mikhaellopez.circularimageview.CircularImageView
                        android:id="@+id/place_logo"
                        android:layout_width="120dp"
                        android:layout_height="100dp"
                        android:src="@drawable/mac_img"
                        app:civ_border_color="@color/color_00c8f8"
                        app:civ_border_width="1dp"
                        app:civ_shadow="true"
                        app:civ_shadow_color="#3f51b5"/>
```

and this is my adapter class:

```
package com.example.chamatestapp

import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import android.widget.TextView
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
import com.cuboid.cuboidcirclebutton.CuboidButton
import com.example.chamatestapp.Model.Place
import com.facebook.drawee.view.SimpleDraweeView
import com.mikhaellopez.circularimageview.CircularImageView
import java.util.*

class PlacesAdapter : RecyclerView.Adapter<PlacesAdapter.ViewHolder>() {

    var placeList: MutableList<Place> = ArrayList()

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder, position: Int) {
        val place: Place = placeList[position]

        holder.textViewName.text = place.name
        place.photos?.get(0)?.photo_reference?.let {
            val url =
                "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/photo?photoreference=${place.photos!![0].photo_reference}&maxwidth=600&key=my_key"
            holder.placeImage.setImageURI(url)

        }
    }

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ViewHolder {
        val v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.recycler_item, parent, false)
        return ViewHolder(v)
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return placeList.size

    }

    fun insertPlaces(body: Array<Place>) {
        placeList.clear()
        body.let {
            placeList.addAll(it)
        }
        notifyDataSetChanged()
    }

    class ViewHolder(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {
        val textViewName = itemView.findViewById(R.id.titleTxt) as TextView
        val placeImage = itemView.findViewById(R.id.placeImage) as SimpleDraweeView
        val place_logo = itemView.findViewById(R.id.place_logo) as CircularImageView
    }


}
```

and this is the Place model:

```
package com.example.chamatestapp.Model

class Place {
    lateinit var types: Array<String>
    var business_status: String? = null
    var icon: String? = null
    var rating: String? = null
    var photos: Array<Photos>? = null
    var reference: String? = null
    var user_ratings_total: String? = null
    var price_level: String? = null
    var scope: String? = null
    var name: String? = null
    var opening_hours: Opening_hours? = null
    var geometry: Geometry? = null
    var vicinity: String? = null
    var id: String? = null
    var plus_code: Plus_code? = null
    var place_id: String? = null

    override fun toString(): String {
        return "ClassPojo [types = $types, business_status = $business_status, icon = $icon, rating = $rating, photos = $photos, reference = $reference, user_ratings_total = $user_ratings_total, price_level = $price_level, scope = $scope, name = $name, opening_hours = $opening_hours, geometry = $geometry, vicinity = $vicinity, id = $id, plus_code = $plus_code, place_id = $place_id]"
    }
}
```

I just need to add the icon in the circular image part like shown in the below figure:

[image: Circle Image]

Comment: Hi there, first of all, I would like to mention that, an ```url(type String)``` is not an ```Uri(type Uri)```, so you can't set a string value inside ```imageView.setImageUri()``` method. the method was not expecting an ```url``` rather than an ```Uri```; that's why your image wasn't loading properly. Secondly, Can I ask you how did you exactly loaded the image in your recyclerview at the beginning? @Mahmoud

Comment: @SaadatSayem thanks for you comment.... What do you mean how I load the image in the recyclerview?? you mean that I'll load the icon using the same way as I load the image?

Comment: I can see your code. If I'm not wrong, you were trying to load an `url` from the API response which was `String` but you're trying to treat that image `url` as an icon. Actually, an icon is also an image. If you were using raw icon or image from you device or storage an `Uri` could be formed. Like you select an image using image picker mechanism. But when you are trying to load image URL from server you should use an image loader mechanism or library. I hope you get it.

Comment: @SaadatSayem I tried to load like the way I loaded the image but I got some error :(

Comment: Please share both code snippets, better if you add those and update your question.

Answer (score 2):

From what I understand of your question you are trying to load an image from a url into a view. For that matter, I also see that you are using SimpleDraweeView. to use it you have to call `mSimpleDraweeView.setImageURI(uri);` and you should be able to load your image. If you are not being able to load it, you may need to add a hierarchy before it.Check these [docs](https://frescolib.org/docs/using-simpledraweeview.html) where the hierarchy is explained. Besides Fresco, you can also use libraries like picasso or glide to inflate them. I'll put an example with Glide where you can use it like this:

```
Glide.with(context)
                .load(yourphotourl)
                .apply(RequestOptions().override(yoursizewidth, yoursizeheight))
                .addListener(object: RequestListener<Drawable>{
                    override fun onLoadFailed(e: GlideException?, model: Any?, target: Target<Drawable>?, isFirstResource: Boolean
                    ): Boolean {
                       //handle failure
                        return false
                    }

                    override fun onResourceReady(resource: Drawable?, model: Any?, target: Target<Drawable>?, dataSource: DataSource?, isFirstResource: Boolean
                    ): Boolean {
                        //file loaded correctly
                        return false
                    }

                })
                .into(yourphotoView)
```

To use glide you need to add the dependency to your app's build gradle file.

```
 //glide
implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.11.0'
annotationProcessor 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.11.0'
```

Let me know if it works!

Comment: thanks a lot for your answer ,I appreciate that, please if you could discuss more for how can put the code you shared in the related code adapter class, please check the updated question as-well :)